# Speed/structure optimization for a recursive tree

Tags: python, performance, optimization, nested

**Edit -> short version:**

In Python, unlike in C, if I pass a parameter to a function I -say: a dict-, the changes made within the function call will reflect outside (as if I passed a pointer instead of just the value)

I want to avoid this so:

- -> I make a copy of my dict and pass the copy to my function

But the values of my dict can be some dict and this goes on until an undefinite depth

- -> the recursive copy is very long.

**Question**: what is a pythonic way to go about this?

---

**Long version:**

I'm coding a master-mind playing robot with a n-digit code in Python.

> You try to guess the code and for each try you get an answer in terms of how many white/black/none you have, meaning resp. "good digit good position"/"good digit wrong position"/"wrong digit" (but you don't know to which digit the whites/blacks/none refer)

I analyze the answers and build a tree of possibilities with a dictionary storing white/black/none.
I store a map of the possible positions of the numbers 0-9 within the code (a digit can appear more than once) in a list.

Ex: for a 3-digit game I will have [[x,y1,y2,y3][-1,0,1,4][...][...][][][][][][]] with:

- x: the total number of times this digit appears in the code (default value being n+1, ie. 4 in the exemple) with positive meaning sure and negative "at least"
- y1,y2,..,yn the position within the code: 1 means I know the digit is in this position, 0 I know it's not, and 4 (or anything) as default
- In my exemple: I know that '1' appears at least once in the code (-1) that it is present in position 2 and that it is NOT present in position 1 and that position 3 is still hypothetically possible.

While I explore my tree of possibilities, I update this list. Which means that each branch of the tree will have its own copy of the list.
Since I recently discovered that, unlike in C, when I pass my list to a sub-method, any change made to it within the sub will reflect on the list outside, I manually copy my list each time with a small method:

```
def bak_symb(_s):

    _b = [[z for z in _s[i]] for i in xrange(10)]
    return _b
```

Now, I profiled my programm and noticed that 90% of the time is spent either in

- append()
  (the branches of my tree are nested dictionaries {w:{},b:0,n:{}} to which I append each branch of possibilities that I explore)For each branch : the programm has to find a n-digit code
  or
- my copying function

So I have three questions.

1. Is there a way to make this function faster?
2. Is there a something better adapted than the structures I chose (2-depth list for the symbols and nested dict for the hypothesis)
3. Is there a more adequate way of doing this than building this huge tree

All comments and remarks are welcome.
I'm self-taught in and might have missed some obvious pythonic way of doing some things.

Last but not least, I tried to find a good compromise between making this short and clear, here again don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Have you tried using `copy`?. `import copy` and in your function do `_b = copy.copy(_s)` instead. If you want to profile better, consider splitting the code into individual functions and then see which one takes the most amount of time.

Comment: Your function `bak_symb` seems to be doing something other than just a simple copy.

Comment: If I do:  _b = copy.copy(a)_ and then _b[0] = 5_ the value of  _a[0]_ will be modified too. Because of this: 1) I don't understand the difference between _b = copy(a)_ and _b = a_ and more importantly 2) that doesn't solve my problem. Using deepcopy does the trick but it's even slower than my bak_symb function  :)

Comment: The thing is: copy doesn't work for nested dicts/list. If I do `a = {1:0,2:{1:0,2:0}}` then `b = a.copy()` and `b[2][2] = 5` I will impact `a` as well; and the deepcopy function is slower than my `bak_symb` routine